# Use Cloudconvert API to convert PDF to PNG

Tags: php

I was trying to use CloudConvert PHP SDK to request a convert job but it always return an empty export file.
The code is from CloudConvert PHP SDK github but I have no idea where I code wrong

Any help for this?
This is the code I used:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use CloudConvert\CloudConvert;
use CloudConvert\Models\Job;
use CloudConvert\Models\Task;

    $input_file_path = 'file path to upload folder after using move_uploaded_file()';   
    $output_file_path      = str_replace( ".pdf", ".svg", $input_file_path );

    $cloudconvert = new CloudConvert(['api_key' => 'My API key']);

    $convertJob = (new Job())
       ->addTask(
           (new Task('import/upload', 'importFile'))
         )
       ->addTask(
           (new Task('convert', 'convertFile'))
             ->set('input_format', 'pdf')
             ->set('output_format', 'svg')
             ->set('engine', 'mupdf')
             ->set('input', ["importFile"])
             ->set('text_to_path', true)
             ->set('filename', 'output.svg')
             ->set('timeout', 200)
             ->set('engine_version', '1.19.0')
         )
       ->addTask(
           (new Task('export/url', 'exportFile'))
             ->set('input', ["convertFile"])
             ->set('inline', true)
             ->set('archive_multiple_files', true)
         ); 

    $cloudconvert->jobs()->create($convertJob);

    $uploadTask = $convertJob->getTasks()->whereName('importFile')[0];

    $cloudconvert->tasks()->upload($uploadTask, fopen($input_file_path, 'r'), $fileName);

    $cloudconvert->jobs()->wait($convertJob);

    $export_urls = $convertJob->getExportUrls();
    if (!empty($export_urls)) { 
        foreach ($export_urls as $file) {
            $source = $cloudconvert->getHttpTransport()->download($file->url)->detach();
            file_put_contents($output_file_path, $source);
        }
        return $output_file_path;
    }
    else {
        $message = 'Error while convert file!!';
        return $message;
    }
```